# How to transpose from rows to column based on conditions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains these four columns - soil type, total hours, volume and Month-year.

I have come up with two queries to generate total hours and total volume by their soil type based on Month-year condition.

Below are my outputs:

Total hour by soil type:

```
SELECT 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year],
    SUM([Total Hour]) AS 'Total_Hour' 
FROM 
    OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL 
WHERE 
    [Month/Year] = '2019-10-01' 
GROUP BY 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year] 
ORDER BY 
    [Soil Type]
```

Output:

[image]

Total Volume by Soil Type:

```
SELECT 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year],
    SUM([Volume]) AS 'Total Volume' 
FROM 
    OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL 
WHERE 
    [Month/Year] = '2019-10-01' 
GROUP BY 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year] 
ORDER BY 
    [Soil Type]
```

Output:

[image]

I have been trying to figure out how to combine these queries in such a way that the SQL statement will first check if the Total Volume of that soil type is > 10000 and if it meets the condition, it will divide the Total Volume by Total Hours of that soil type. The SQL should then transpose the soil type column into row as shown below:

[image]

I tried using the SQL PIVOT function but unable to produce the above output that I need. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correct understand your problem, try this:

```
declare @product table(
 [Soil Type] varchar(50),
 [Month/Year] smalldatetime,
 [Total Hour] int,
 [Volume] int
)

insert into @product values ('Clay', '20190101', 2, 20)
insert into @product values ('Clay', '20190101', 3, 10)
insert into @product values ('Sandy', '20190101', 4, 10)
insert into @product values ('Sandy', '20190201', 2, 25)
insert into @product values ('Clay', '20190301', 8, 40)
insert into @product values ('Mixed', '20190101', 2, 25)
insert into @product values ('Mixed', '20190102', 1, 20)
insert into @product values ('Sand', '20190101', 3, 30)
insert into @product values ('Sand', '20190101', 1, 2)
insert into @product values ('Clay', '20190101', 1, 15)


Select [date], Clay, Mixed, Sand, Sandy
FROM(
SELECT 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year] as [date],
    SUM([Volume]) / SUM([Total Hour]) as _data
FROM 
   @product
GROUP BY 
    [Soil Type], [Month/Year]
HAVING SUM([Volume])>30) x
PIVOT (
  SUM(_data) FOR [Soil Type] IN (Clay, Mixed, Sand, Sandy)
) pvt
```